# Creating favicon with letter from .ttf file

Tags: favicon

I would like to make a simple favicon icon.
It would be a simple icon, just a letter in a specific font with a particular color and a background color:

I have the font-family with a .ttf file and that is it.

How can i make a logo with this information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a screenshot (with that letter in a very big font size big) and use that graphic file.

Comment: Least sexy solution ever, but by far the most pragmatic :)